# Calculate the total of liabilities and check it is matching with the given value

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I want to calculate the total liabilities amount from webtable and need to compare with the total amount which is present on webpage.

**I got the following error :**

```
Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1
\L
 ^
```

**My code is :**

```
{
totalLiabilities = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(text(),'Liabilities :')]")).getText();
        logger.info(totalLiabilities);
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[-+^:$,a-zA-Z0-9]");
        Matcher matchh = patt.matcher(totalLiabilities);
        while(matchh.find())
        {
            String s2 = matchh.group();
            System.out.println(s2);
            totalLiabilities = totalLiabilities.replaceAll("\\"+s2, "");
        }
        totalLiabilities=totalLiabilities.replace("Liabilities", "");
        logger.info("total liabilities : "+totalLiabilities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. `replace` would also replace all the occurrences but won't use regular expression for that - just a char sequence. If you still need to replace the values by a regular expression you need to add `\\` to your double-slash.